# PHP MongoDB\Client updateOne add new field to existing document array

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I'm struggling to update a document and add new elements (fields) into it's existing array without losing the array elements on update.

This is my code which inserts a new document into the collection if it doesn't already exist (upsert):

```
$updateResult = $collection->findOneAndUpdate(
            [
                'recording-id' => $out['recording']->id
            ],
            ['$set'  => [
                'release'            =>    [
                    'id'            => $out['release']->id, 
                    'title'         => $out['release']->title,
                    'date'          => $out['release']->date,
                    'country'       => $out['release']->country
                ],
                'artist'            => [
                    'id'            => $out['artist']->id,
                    'name'          => $out['artist']->name,
                ],
                'recording'         => [
                    'id'            => $out['recording']->id,
                    'title'         => $out['recording']->title,
                    'score'         => $out['recording']->score,
                    'length'        => $out['recording']->length,
                    'release-count' => count($out['recording']->releases),
                ],
                'release-group'     => [
                    'id'            => $out['release-group']['id'],
                    'title'         => $out['release-group']['title'],
                    'first-release-date'=>$out['release-group']['first-release-date'],
                    'primary-type'  => $out['release-group']['primary-type'],
                    'musicbrainz'   => $out['release-group']['musicbrainz'],
                    'url-rels'      => $out['release-group']['url-rels'],
                    'coverart'      => $out['release-group']['coverart']
                ],
                'execution'         => [
                    'firstfind'     => $out['execution']->time
                ]


            ]
        ],
        ['upsert'           => true,
        'projection'        => 
        [ 
            '_id'               => 0,
             'release'          => 1, 
             'artist'           => 1,
             'recording'        => 1,
             'release-group'    => 1,
             'execution'        => 1


        ],
        'returnDocument'    => MongoDB\Operation\FindOneAndUpdate::RETURN_DOCUMENT_AFTER,
        ]
    );
```

So now I have an existing document in a collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1a6aaf5ecc8001ee858f6c"),
    "recording-id" : "d0d439f9-5324-4728-8706-2da39adb89c5",
    "artist" : {
        "id" : "9d97b077-b28d-4ba8-a3d9-c71926e3b2b6",
        "name" : "Gordon Lightfoot"
    },
    "recording" : {
        "id" : "d0d439f9-5324-4728-8706-2da39adb89c5",
        "title" : "Sundown",
        "score" : 100,
        "length" : 184000,
        "release-count" : 2
    },
    "release" : {
        "id" : "0c008d76-2bc9-44a3-854b-0a08cde89337",
        "title" : "All Live",
        "date" : "2012-04-24",
        "country" : "CA"
    },
    "release-group" : {
        "id" : "0a5d5f33-8e9d-4fa4-b622-a95e4218a3c4",
        "title" : "All Live",
        "first-release-date" : "2012-04-24",
        "primary-type" : "Album",
        "musicbrainz" : "https://musicbrainz.org/release-group/0a5d5f33-8e9d-4fa4-b622-a95e4218a3c4",
        "url-rels" : "https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release-group/0a5d5f33-8e9d-4fa4-b622-a95e4218a3c4?inc=url-rels&fmt=json",
        "coverart" : null
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to update this document, and add new fields into the arrays. The new fields are to be added to certain fields. 
Here is the code doing that:

```
$collection         = (new MongoDB\Client)->stream->musicbrainz;
    $updateResult = $collection->updateOne(
        [
            'recording-id' => $out['recording']['id']
        ],
        ['$addToSet'  => [
            'artist'            => [
                'wikiQiD'       => $out['artist']['qid'],
                'wiki-extract'  => $out['artist']['wiki-extract'],
                'wiki-pageid'   => $out['artist']['pageid'],
            ],
            'release-group'     => [
                'wikiQiD'       => $out['release-group']['qid'],
                'wiki-extract'  => $out['release-group']['wiki-extract']
            ]
        ]
    ],

    [
        'upsert'           => true,
        'returnDocument'    => MongoDB\Operation\FindOneAndUpdate::RETURN_DOCUMENT_AFTER,
    ]
);
```

I've noticed there's "$addToSet" and "$push" commands, and could use assistance with what the difference is between these two commands.

> If the field is absent in the document to update, $push adds the array
>   field with the value as its element.
>
> The $addToSet operator adds a value to an array unless the value is
>   already present, in which case $addToSet does nothing to that array.

I did some googling, and reading of the MongoDB/Client UpdateOne function, but can't seem to find a way to append these fields to the existing arrays.

The error I'm getting is:

`Fatal error:  Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\BulkWriteException: The field 'artist' must be an array but is of type object in document {_id: ObjectId('5d1a6aaf5ecc8001ee858f6c')} in ...`

I know the following:

1. It could be my document, as it's not a proper array that Fatal error is complaining about.
2. It could be my `findOneAndUpdate' formatting, and I'm not doing that correctly.
3. It could be both and I have it all wrong from the very start.

Any insight or constructive criticism is appreciated, just refrain from flames, pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the working code I finally use to get it do what I want it to.

It's a simple matter of just setting your field names and values and mongo will update the found record replacing it with the array sent to it. No need to push or anything.

```
function firstFindMongoUpdate($out) {
$collection         = (new MongoDB\Client)->stream->musicbrainz;
$updateResult = $collection->findOneAndUpdate(
        [
            'recording-id'          => $out['recording']->id
        ],
        ['$set'  => [

                'query'             => $out['query'],

                'release'           =>    [
                    'id'            => $out['release']->id, 
                    'title'         => $out['release']->title,
                    'date'          => $out['release']->date,
                    'country'       => $out['release']->country,
                    'label'         => $out['release']->label,
                ],
                'artist'            => [
                    'id'            => $out['artist']->id,
                    'name'          => $out['artist']->name, 
                    'wiki'          => $out['artist']->wiki,
                ],
                'recording'         => [
                    'id'            => $out['recording']->id,
                    'title'         => $out['recording']->title, // sometimes contains apostophe ie; Bill‘s Love (option ] key)
                    'score'         => $out['recording']->score,
                    'length'        => $out['recording']->length,
                    'release-count' => count($out['recording']->releases)
                ],
                'release-group'     => [
                    'id'            => $out['release-group']['id'],
                    'title'         => $out['release-group']['title'],
                    'first-release-date'=>$out['release-group']['first-release-date'],
                    'primary-type'  => $out['release-group']['primary-type'],
                    'musicbrainz'   => $out['release-group']['musicbrainz'],
                    'url-rels'      => $out['release-group']['url-rels'],
                    'coverart'      => $out['release-group']['coverart'],
                    'wiki'          => $out['release-group']['wiki']
                ],
                'execution'         => [ 
                    'artistQuery'   => $out['execution']->artistQuery,
                    'recordingQuery'=> $out['execution']->recordingQuery,
                    'time'          => $out['execution']->time
                ]

        ]
    ],
    ['upsert'           => true,
    'projection'        => 
        [ 
        '_id'             => 1,
         'query'          => 1,
         'release'        => 1, 
         'artist'         => 1,
         'recording'      => 1,
         'release-group'  => 1,
         'execution'      => 1

        ],
        'returnDocument'    => MongoDB\Operation\FindOneAndUpdate::RETURN_DOCUMENT_AFTER,
    ]
);
```